# Margically appearing margin in footer. Could use some fresh eyes on this

Tags: css

Got a nearly finished coded comp here:
http://clients.pixelbleed.net/biodesign/

I realize it's not completely valid, what with my nesting of li's and ul's within A tags. Unfortunately that's the way it has to be.

My issue is with the very bottom of the footer. It has a space showing the body's background color beneath it. Tried a number of things and this space after the black link bar on the very bottom is a resistant little bugger.

Ideally the black box on the bottom should rest against the very base of the view-port, at least when the content is sufficiently long--which it is in this case.

If someone would like to take a quick peak at my source and give me some ideas I'd be very grateful. The CSS can be found here: http://clients.pixelbleed.net/biodesign/css/core.css

And, yes, I've tried removing the height:100%. Makes no difference it seems. I do believe the issue to be with the footer, as when I remove these Div's the content rests as it should. Just don't see anything in my CSS to cause the margin/spacing issue though.

Thanks so much.

Comment: in what browser? chrome works 100%

Answer (score 2):

if you just remove the class "group" from asufooter-wrapper, the margin disappears.

Comment: Nice catch. And the style is `.group:after { content: "."; ... visibility:hidden; }` which is going to insert the period after the group and calculate space for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but one way to fix it is apply:

```
#asufooter-wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The problem seems to be caused by some wrapping. However, I tried editing your white-space and widths to no avail.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks brother.